# how to use a mask texture?

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl

A texture pack for a sponza model contains mask textures (black and white). I guess that I should read only a red channel from that texture, right ? I use deferred rendering and for  shading calculations I use additive blending. A result is first save in a texture (for some post-process operations), so doesn't go directly to the default framebuffer. How to use a mask texture ?

Answer (score 2):

Mask textures basically let you choose different shading branches depending on texels info.

For example simplest reflection mask `Result = Ambient.rgb + Mix(Diffuse.rgb * Texture.rgb, Reflection.rgb, Mask.r);` will mask certain areas as reflective and others as normal.

Depending on mask texture format, e.g. `GL_RGB` it may have each channel used for different purpose (`r` for specular, `g` for reflection, `b` for something else). OpenGL allows number of texture format that have just one component `GL_LUMINANCE` if you need only one mask.